# Why one cannot equate a sphere and a plane but a sphere with a sphere?

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-geometry, spheres, intersection-theory

This is a general question about the intersection of a sphere with a plane or sphere which is confusing me.

To find the intersection between two spheres K1 and K2, you can equate them, solve the equation K1=K2, and find the intersection plane.
But the same procedure is not possible between a sphere (K) and a plane (P). One cannot just solve the equation K=P and gets the circle. But I don't understand why? Can anyone explain this?

Edit:
As an example:
Let K : (x-1)² +(y-9)² + (z-4)² -85=0 be the sphere in 3d and P: 6x-2y+3z-49=0 be a plane. Why can't I just solve the equation K=P and get the intersection circle?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understad either why you don't obtain a circle. In what form would you want your circle to be described?

Comment: What kind of equations are you using to describe a sphere or a plane? There are more ways to do that. Can you please show us an example?

Comment: @Hume2 Let K : (x-1)² +(y-9)² + (z-4)² -85=0 be the sphere in 3d and P: 6x-2y+3z-49=0 be a plane. Why can't I just solve the equation K=P and get the intersection circle?

Comment: Actually, this shouldn't work even for two spheres. Can you please give us also an example of two spheres for which is does work?

Comment: You seem to me to be confusing the intersection, which is a circle, with the intersection plane which is the plane in which the intersection lives.

Comment: Maybe my english is not that good ^^ But if you have the intersection plane, you can find the center point of the "circular" and radius on this plane, right? But my question is like, why can't you even obtain that by the equation K=P. But after reading the other answers, I think my thought-process about intersections is wrong.

Comment: A circle in $3$-space can be given as the intersection of a sphere and a plane; the plane is given by the circle, but the sphere can vary. You can even use some other quadrics. Two spheres that intersect in more than a point also gives a circle. This cancelling the quadratic terms of the spheres business, gives you the plane, that together with either of the two spheres gives such a representation of a circle. The missing notion seems to be that of a _pencil_: two spheres define a pencil $K_1+\lambda K_2=0,$ one member of which is the plane that cuts the intersection circle from either sphere.

Comment: Also, geogebra gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS8tW.png).

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with geometry. The real problem is that saying $K=0$ and $P=0$ is **NOT** equivalent to saying $K=P$.

Example: In the real plane, the system $x=0$ and $y=0$ yields a single point $(0,0)$, while $x=y$ yields a line.

The fact that your false recipe $K=P$ works in a particular case is a pure coincidence (the proof is that tomi gave you a counterexample where your method  does not work).

Comment: That makes sense! But then why one can do this with two spheres?

Comment: we can't ! As I said, it is pure coincidence that you recipe works in your particular case

Answer (score 4):

You have to be a little careful in your formulation.

First, as mentioned in comments, it isn't true that $K_1=K_2$ gives *the [circle of] intersection* of the two spheres. Rather, it gives *the plane of* the circle of intersection. (This plane is the analogue of a [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis), the line containing the points of intersection of two circles.)

Second, it's not even necessarily true that $K_1=K_2$ gives the equation of that plane. That magic works when (and only when) $K_1$ and $K_2$ have matching coefficients on $x^2$, $y^2$, $z^2$, because then (and only then) do those terms cancel in $K_1=K_2$; what remains is a linear equation in $x$, $y$, $z$: the target plane.

A problem, though, is that there's no *a priori* reason for those coefficients to match. Both $x^2+y^2+z^2-3=0$ and $4x^2+4y^2+4z^2-12=0$ represent the same sphere; *either* could be "$K_1$". And *neither* will yield a sphere when simply set equal to a "$K_2$" of the form $3(x-4)^2+3(y+5)^2+3(z-6)^2-7=0$.

Almost-certainly, you're assuming $K_1$ and $K_2$ to be in "standard form", with necessarily-matching coefficients of $1$ on their second-degree terms; that's not an *unreasonable* assumption (standard form is common), but it *is* an assumption and so must be stated explicitly. An alternative approach is to restate things thusly:

> If $K_1(x,y,z)=0$ and $K_2(x,y,z)=0$ represent two spheres, then there are non-zero values $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $k_1 K_1 = k_2 K_2$ is the equation of the plane containing the circle of intersection (if any).

(Specifically, we take $k_1$ to be the coefficient of $x^2$ (and $y^2$ and $z^2$)  in $K_2$, and $k_2$ to be the corresponding coefficient in $K_1$. This guarantees that those terms cancel.)

The advantage of the restatement is that it applies when, say, $K_1=0$ represents a plane instead of a sphere. Since we end up taking $k_2=0$ (as $K_1$ has no second-degree terms), the equation $k_1 K_1=k_2 K_2$ reverts to $K_1=0$, as expected; after all, the plane containing the circle of intersection *is* that original plane.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not true that the intersection between two spheres is a plane.
E.g., consider the two spheres
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ and $$(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2=1,$$ the intersection gives
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2+y^2+z^2=1\\
2x=1
\end{array}\right.
$$
which is not a plane, but the a circonference that lies in the plane $2x=1$ and is contained in the spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$; sure, the system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2=1\\
2x=1
\end{array}\right.
$$
defined the same circumference.

Now, if you consider the plane $2x=1$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, their intersection is again
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2=1\\
2x=1
\end{array}\right.
$$
i.e., the same circumference as above. You can write the same system as
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y^2+z^2=\frac{3}{4}\\
2x=1
\end{array}\right.
$$
namely, you can eliminate the $x$ from the first equation. Now, what represents the equation $y^2+z^2=\frac{3}{4}$? Not a circumference: indeed, it is a cylinder (remember that we are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$), to be precise the cylinder having as directrix the circumference
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2=1\\
2x=1
\end{array}\right.
$$
and axis perpendicular to the plane $2x=1$.

Summing up: an equation as $y^2+z^2=1$ is not a circumference in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but a cylinder, the equation of a circumference in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is always given by a system, the same holds for a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, indeed $2x=1$ is a plane $\mathbb{R}^3$, and a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.